# How do you use Pakyow around hooks?

Tags: routes, hook, pakyow

Looking around the docs (http://pakyow.com/docs/routing), I don't see an example for routing around hooks, so I assumed the following:

```
fn :around_hook do
  :do_some_stuff
  yield
  :do_some_more_stuff
end

get :named_route, '/named_route_path', around: [:around_hook] do
  :doing_stuff_in_the_middle
end
```

But as the server responds with a 500 error and the stack track shows `no block given (yield)`, I guess my assumption is wrong.

Seems like I must be thinking about the around hook wrong, or maybe just made a simple mistake. Anyway, looking for an answer.

Comment: P.S. Getting around (no pun intended) this by using a single before and after hook, but I don't like it =)

Comment: Ok, so exactly why are you calling `yield`?

Comment: I was just assuming that that would be how it works, like normal ruby blocks.  Otherwise, how will it know where in the block it should execute the code in the route block.

Comment: It executes as a stack of functions. So, when you say around Pakyow will execute like this: around_hook, route_fn, around_hook.

Comment: Aha! Ok. I guess I was confused about the name because of the around action in Rails, but makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my basic understanding of the around hook was wrong.  It actually executes twice, once before and then once after the route block.

```
fn :around_hook do
  :do_this_before_and_after
end

get :route, '/route', around: [:around_hook] do 
  :do_this_in_the_middle
end
```

Thanks @bryanp